# magento - 504 Gateway Time-out, server didn't respond in time

Tags: php, magento

I have developed a ecommerce portal for interior designing using magento, Once i load the url now its displaying ***504 Gateway Time-out  The server didn't respond in time.***

So i request any one to please suggest the solution for this.
 url : http://desireddesigns.in/shop/

Answer (score 0):

`php.ini` file and  increase execution time(**`max_execution_time`**)

```
max_execution_time = 3000
```